# Scroll don't work, if mouse above fixed block

Tags: html, css, block, fixed

I have a problem. Fixed block on the page blocked scroll if my mouse above this block.
My example:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.body_block {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffdd56;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #a9eceb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6b42vsq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6b42vsq/4/
Here is the final css:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.body_block {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffdd56;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #a9eceb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Rise Ledger, thank you for you answer!
But in this version no hidden content from page (if page have more contents then pop-up window).
Example this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/u6b42vsq/5/

Comment: This green where it is written "This is test content" should be a popup window that take all size of content? or what exactly I do not understand

Comment: Rise Ledger, `body` hac more contents then `body_block`, but window size must be = `body_block`, everything else is hidden.

Comment: Do not understand 100% what you will need, but for example if you want to use body_block as a popup and have everything that is on body not visible, then you will add to body_block the following css: position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:1001; And this will hide all that is on body.